# Binding dynamic props to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Using vue 2.x and vuetify 1.5x I am trying to bind a dynamic prop name to a vuetify component. The `v-tooltip` accepts a prop for the location of the tooltip can be `bottom`, `right` etc. The way you would normally pass the prop would be like so:

```
<v-tooltip bottom></v-tooltip>
//alternatively
<v-tooltip :bottom="true"></v-tooltip>
```

What I am trying to do is bind a dynamic value that can be any of the values, here are some of the options that have not worked:

```
<v-tooltip {{tooltipLocation}}></v-tooltip>
//OR
<v-tooltip v-bind={tooltipLocation: true}></v-tooltip>
```

These two attempts created an $attr on v-tooltip but did not pass down the prop.

```
<v-tooltip v-bind={`${tootltipLocation}`: true}></v-tooltip>
```

This apparently is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this can be done with a computed property like so:

```
computed: {
            dynamicTooltipProps() {
                return {
                    [`${this.tooltipLocation}`]: true
                }
            }

        }
```